# 8-bit modulo 256 sum CRC

Tags: c#, crc

I have a class for my protocol header in C#

```
public class Header
{
    public UInt16 m_syncBytes;
    public UInt16 m_DestAddress;
    public UInt16 m_SourceAddress;

    public byte m_Protocol;
    public byte m_SequnceNumber;

    public byte m_Length;
    public byte m_HdrCrc;
}
```

I want to calculate an 8-bit modulo 256 sum of header block characters from `m_DestAddress` to `m_Length`

I have come across a lot of examples for 16 bit CRC's online.But couldn't find 8 bit Modulo 256 sum CRC. It would be great if someone could explain how to calculate that.

Comment: Can't you just `byte crc = (byte)(bytes.Take(m_Length).Sum() % 256);`?

Comment: @itsme86 - `m_Length` is not the length of the header. It is the length of the data portion

Comment: You said you want to create a CRC of header block characters, but then you're talking about from `m_DestAddress` to `m_Length` which you say is in the data portion. It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you saying the bytes of the header? Like 6 bytes? How are you storing the header in memory? You have to be careful about assumptions made about how .Net is storing those properties internally then. Or just add the values of the header elements you want to include in the CRC together and then modulo them.

Comment: @itsme86 - The `m_Length` field represents length of the data which follows the above header. The checksum here relates only to the fields in the header. What I am trying to say is you can't do `Take(m_Length)` because you will be taking too much. We are talking about 7 bytes here

Comment: So then how about (m_DestAddress + m_SourceAddress...) % 256?

Comment: You'll probably want to take the 16-bit values 1 byte at a time though. Endianness doesn't matter since you're just taking the sum. `(m_DestAddress  & 0xFF) + (m_DestAddress >> 8)`. Same for the source address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I'd do it:

```
public byte GetCRC()
{
    int crc;  // 32-bits is more than enough to hold the sum and int will make it easier to math
    crc = (m_DestAddress & 0xFF) + (m_DestAddress >> 8);
    crc += (m_SourceAddress & 0xFF) + (m_SourceAddress >> 8);
    crc += m_Protocol;
    crc += m_SequenceNumber;
    crc += m_Length;

    return (byte)(crc % 256);  // Could also just do return (byte)(crc & 0xFF);
}
```

Comment: If you explain what you are doing and why you'll probably get more upvotes. And you'll also follow the SO guidelines ;)